# Hive copy schema without partitions or remove paritioning

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform, beeline

I'm trying to create a table and copy another table's schema like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table LIKE old_table;
```

When I do this, because `old_table` is a partitioned, external table, it partitions `new_table` as well. I don't need or want `new_table` to be partitioned, I essentially just want the column definitions. There are a lot of them, and I have do this kind of thing often in my pipeline, so I'm essentially being lazy because I don't want a huge mess of column definitions spattered throughout my script.

Can I either copy the table schema and ignore partitioning, or can I at least remove partitioning once `new_table` is created? I have managed to find a way to drop partitions, but not to remove partitioning altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query to create `new_table` without partitions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. I might have to use something like this if I can't find a way to ignore partitions otherwise.